# Trying to find a book I read about a boy with supernatural powers who lives in the woods

Tags: story-identification, books

I want to find this book I read in about 2016. It's about a girl who meets this boy who has black hair and a black horse, he lives in the woods alone. She gets to know him and finds out he is something supernatural. I know there is something with dreams. And her dad is also something supernatural. In the end these women come for him (he was hiding), and there was a fight and I don't really remember it but he left to protect her. And it's a book series.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?